# Javascript to open mobile app also open fallback url

Tags: javascript, html, ios

im pretty noob to web development.
this `js` code open my mobile app when the page is loaded:

```
        function startMyApp() {
        document.getElementById("IOSClick").href = "appUrlScheme://";
        document.getElementById("IOSClick").click();

        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "https://www.google.com"; //fallback url
        }, 300);
    }
```

i have a problem (not on all devices) where the script open my `iOS` app but when the timeout hits the `fallback url` also get opened. so the user see the web page -> mobile app -> web browser with fallback url.

how can i control when the timeout hits it can make a decision weather the page is visible or not (if not visible the app probably opened and should do nothing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) inside the setTimeout which fires when  HTML document has been completely loaded. It does not wait for the stylesheet